# Read protected properties

Tags: delphi, properties

I have a class that derives from Twincontrol. I want to read controls font, caption, and width but all these properties are protected, So i cannot read them directly.To read these property i have created a class as show below

```
  TTest = class(TWinControl)
  public
    procedure test(A: TWinControl);
  end;

procedure TTest.test(A: TWinControl);
var
 width: integer;
 text: string;
begin
  width := A.width;  // cannot access
  text := a.caption;  //cannot access
end;
```

calling this function

```
ABC := TTest.create(nil);
Abc.Test(twincontrol(Tbutton));
```

How can i access these properties?
Do i have to derived class from other base class?
i want to read these properties at top most level as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.  Subclass TWinControl, at which point you can access it's protected members: http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm

Comment: when i do showmessage(a.caption) compiler gives me error.

Comment: Read the article.  If it still doesn't make sense, 1) Update your post showing the code that's giving the error, 2) Copy/paste the exact error message.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 , 
I got it, the reason it was not working for me is because I was not typecasting the control with TTest

Comment: @paulsm4 the code in the question is clear, no need for an update. Asker is not applying the protected hack.